# How to set event trigger with containername/*/pathname in ADF?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, eventtrigger

My blob storage have path like this

```
ctn/team1/Raw
   /team2/Raw
   /team3/Raw
```

I want to trigger ADF pipeline when blob is created in any Raw path.
How to config event trigger in this case ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have the trigger setting as below :

`Blob path begins with = team` - (assuming 'ctn' as container)

In case if 'ctn' is not a container and a root folder then you can have `Blob path begins with = ctn/team`

[image]

**Note**: In case if you have multiple sub-folders under `team*/` (see below example) , then the above setting will create events for all the blobs that were created in the subfolders (RAW, RAW2, ..)

For example:

```
ctn/team1/Raw
         /Raw2
         /Raw3    
   /team2/Raw
         /Raw2
   /team3/Raw
         /Raw2
```

Currently events triggers do not support wildcards in the path. And if you have multiple sub folders and want to create events for a specific sub folder as mentioned in above example, then you will have to create event triggers with specific paths.

Hope this helps.